# Where can I download the msvcrt.dll that offers function rand_s?

Tags: gstreamer, glib, msvcrt

I was trying to run the [GStreamer hello-world demo](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735), after successful compilation, but the application doesn't run as expected. An error message pops up and the application quits. The message says the msvcrt.dll in my computer doesn't have function `rand_s`. The Dependency Walker is shown below.
[image]
I'm pretty sure it is libglib-2.0-0.dll that came with GStreamer caused the trouble. So, where can I download the msvcrt.dll that offers function `rand_s`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problems with InkScape by nulling out _s in rand_s in .dll import table of glib*.dll.

Technically, rand_s are available in msvcr*.dll if you install appropriate redistributable. Having installed sequentially MSVS 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 redistributables, I can see rand_s in msvcr100.dll (2010), msvcr110.dll (2012), msvcr120.dll (2013), but not in msvcrt.dll. msvcr90.dll and msvcr80.dll are missing after installation, I don't know why. It seems that some versions of Windows contain rand_s in msvsrt.dll and FLOSS developers expected it to be true everywhere, but in fact one must link against msvcr*.dll to really get these features.

You can also try to install MSVS redistributable 2010 or higher and copy msvcr*.dll from system32 to gstreamer using msvcrt.dll file name. I haven't tried it.